# Mongoose models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a UserModel schema

```
var UserModel = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String
})
```

and a PageModel schema

```
var PageModel = new Schema({
    _username: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
   name: String,
   content: String
})
```

As a user may have a lot of pages, is there a way to create in Mongo a collection of pages by user instead of having a huge unique collection of all pages with a reference to the owner on each document?

Hope I am clear enough :)

Comment: What you have now is a normalized schema and would by most counts be the proper solution (aside from adding any indexes you might need to make your queries efficient). Mongo is quite adept at storing large collections. Why are you trying to manage a problem that the database is designed to manage for you?

Comment: I am quiet sure a unique collections of all pages will be larger than 16Mb! And for the project I am working on, it will be easier to get a collection by user.

Comment: I think you are confusing max document size and max collection size. See [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) for more information. As for querying, I don't see how querying a single collection for matching documents is any more difficult than querying a dynamic collection for all documents.

Comment: Thank you Jason, for sure my english is not as good as needed for technical understanding!

Comment: Technical documentation can be confusing even if you are a native english speaker :-)

Comment: Taking care about your recommandation is my original request possible by any way?

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to the comments for [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559066/mongoose-models/29563882#comment47276268_29559066) to the OP's question.